# Javascript errors in my Joomla website

Tags: javascript, joomla

my website is marutiindia.in. My website was working fine until I installed a module named lof k2 scroller. The website was showing jquery errors and the module at the lower half of the template was not working. But I managed to get the module to work by adding the following code at the start of the JS file which was showing error:

```
if(jQuery){ 
    jQuery.noConflict(); 
}
```

But, now I am getting other JS errors which I am not able to understand.
Below is the link for the screenshot of errors:

[Screenshot](http://www.screenshots.cc/photos/original/65886-nt2hz.jpg)

I don't know what these errors mean.

Also I have one more plugin to use for my website which also causes scroller to not work.

Please help me resolve these errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla uses Mootools, which also use the `$` function name. in order to avoid this, your plugins either:

- must use `jQuery` instead of `$`. For example, instead of `$('div')` to get divs, use `jQuery('div')`
- if you really want to use `$`, wrap the jQuery code in a closure

  ```
  (function($){

      //code that uses `$`

  }(jQuery))
  ```
- make sure the plugins are extending from `jQuery` and not `$`.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I made changes in the concerned JS files and now I am not getting errors in those files. But as I said I have another plugin to use in my website and this plugin uses JS file and when I enable this plugin I get other JS error as you can see on my website. How should I go about solving this error? Thanks again.

Comment: Basically the use of this plugin is to magnify images and this is the code which uses <a></a> tags: <a href="images/stories/layoutfull.jpg" class="cloud-zoom"><img src="images/stories/layout.jpg" border="0" alt="Amenities in Mid-Town Empire" title="Amenities" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;" /></a></p>

Comment: Sorry Joseph, I am not able to get you as I know very little of how JS works. Can you please tell me where that part of the code will be in the plugin? Or shall I post you the whole plugin as an attachment?

Comment: Please help me understand what you are asking me to give you. I need your help. Please help me.

Comment: Ok. This might be the code the you are asking for: `<script type="text/javascript">

  var _lofmain =  jQuery('lofk2scroller<?php echo $module->id; ?>');`  Hope this helps. Thanks.